# How to show BottomSheet by pulling from the bottom edge of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I'm quite new to Android's `BottomSheet` and I've successfully tried out examples on how to use it but most examples only demonstrate showing/hiding the BottomSheet through View click events.

For now I have the following code:

```
BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;

@Override
protected void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
   mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
   mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
   mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Now, I would just like to know if it's possible to show the BottomSheet, by pulling/dragging from the bottom edge of the screen, when the state is `BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN` and peekHeight is `0`?, similar to the behavior of a DrawerLayout?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think BottomSheetBehavior offers that functionality, but you can intercept touch events in the containing activity and expand the bottom sheet whenever a bottom pull is detected:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bottomPullDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new BottomPullListener());
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return bottomPullDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}


private class BottomPullListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 20;
    private final int displayHeight;
    private boolean beginningOnBottom;

    BottomPullListener() {
        final Point displaySize = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
        displayHeight = displaySize.y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        beginningOnBottom = displayHeight - event.getY() < SWIPE_THRESHOLD;
        return beginningOnBottom;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (beginningOnBottom && e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
            cameraFragment.expandBottomSheet();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```